# How to prove that two logic model are elementarily equivalent?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In what ways can I prove that $M,N$, two logic models are elementarily equivalent (or not)?
Some ways I know:

- Find an isomorphism between the structures
- Find a formula that M satisfies and N doesn't
- Ehrenfeucht Fraisse games (Which I do not fully understand and I don't
  find examples for those on the internet)

Are there any more ways to do it?

More specifically, I want to prove that all of the models satisfying certain conditions are elementarily equivalent (e.g. all of the models that are linear dense orders)

Comment: Well, if you could prove the theory $T$ is complete (for example using quantifier elimination) then necessarily all the models of $T$ would be elementarily equivalent.  That should be the case for the theory of unbounded linear dense orders, I think.

Comment: The Tarski-Vaught criterion gives a very useful necessary and sufficient condition in the case when one of $M$ and $N$ is a substructure of the other. It may help with your specific problem if all the structures in question have a common substructure or you can embed them all in some larger structure.